# Cannot use android:Theme.Material in AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-theme, appcompatactivity

First, I created two styles, one is value and the other is value-21.

In values/styles.xml is

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat"></style>
</resources>
```

In values-v21/styles.xml is

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material"></style>
</resources>
```

My gradle file (app.gradle)

[image: gradle pic1]
[image: gradle pic2]

Since the `ActionBarActivity` is deprecated, so I use `AppCompatActivity`.

When I set these two style values and extend `AppCompatActivity` in `MainActivity`, I got the exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat
theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

I do the two different changes and that exception never shows up again:

- Extend "android.app.Activity" instead of v7.AppCompatActivity.
- Change to "Theme.AppCompat" in values-v21/styles.xml.

Should I extend the "android.app.Activity" if I want to use the design theme?

Or, is there another way to use material design theme?

Thanks.

Comment: Android L can use Theme.Meterial if use AppComatActivity Just use Theme.AppCompat

Comment: What situation will use "android:Theme.Material" ?

Comment: minSdkVersion is 21

Answer (score 2):

Replace Below Theme in your `styles.xml` File.

```
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base">
        <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And use extends AppCompatActivity in your MainActivity.

And Finally use this Theme in Manifestfile.

```
   <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme">
    </application>
```

Gradle File dependencies.

```
    dependencies 
        {
         compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) compile 

'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0' compile 

'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1' compile 

'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.1' // For NavigationView Using Menu 

'compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0' // For Google Map compile 

'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.0' 
      }
```

Edit my theme as you want.
Hope it will Helps...

Comment: please provide your gradle file also

Comment: So dont need to use "android:Theme.Material" at all? Just use Theme.AppCompat?

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Comment: yeah always bro...(:

Comment: Great way to use both material and appcompat

Answer (score 2):

Write the below theme in your style.xml file.

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">any_color_code</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">any_color_codek</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">any_color_code</item>
</style>
```

and write extends AppCompatActivity in your `MainActivity

and in the Manifest.xml file write your application tag as below:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme">
</application>
```

Comment: So dont need to use "android:Theme.Material" at all?

Comment: Yes there is no need to use "android:Theme.Material". It will be handled automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"></style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this** 
style.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyRadioButton" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorRadioon</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorRadioof</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

**style.xml(v 21)**

```
<resources>>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**update Your Gradle File using below code**

**add aaptOption in your gradle**

```
aaptOptions {
        additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
    }

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.jmtechnologies.askuscash"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    }

    // important to run code on kitkat

    aaptOptions {
        additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // multidex
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'


    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'



}
```